# add pages to masterpage gives me javascript error

Tags: asp.net, javascript

i have a page which uses some javascript code to run,it was working fine until i added it to master page, on adding it to master page it gives me an error from javascript

```
var fu1 = document.getElementById("FileUpload1");
 var ex1 = extension(fu1.value) ; object expected in fu1.value
```

i need to know where to add the javascript in master page

Comment: I expect that that name of the FileUpload1 control is being tampered with by the master page setup.

Comment: Added an answer with potential solution

Comment: What's the JS error? That it can't find the FileUpload1?

Comment: what i have spotted out is that it cant get the id of fileupload even in aspx.cs file

Comment: Try ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_FileUpload1

Comment: hi Pandiya Chendur, 
thnx for the response this is working in javascript,,could u plz suggest me how can i get the id of fileupload control in codebehind file

Comment: You need to be accessing the ClientID property of the control (which should output Pandiya's suggestion), and this should generally be available by the time the PageLoad event is called.

Comment: Try to get ID using ,
  String fileuploadid= FileUpload1.ClientID.Tostring();

Print the string and see

Comment: @Sumit Did you resolved it? Try this.FileUpload1.Id in server side or this.Page.FileUpload1.ID

Comment: yeah i have got the response,thnx for ur suggetion too

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var fu1 = document.getElementById("<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>");
var ex1 = extension(fu1.value)
```

Comment: What the error you are getting? Where is your script? Content Page or Master Page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have one of these controls:

```
<input id="FileUpload1" runat="server" type="file" />
```

If so, you can access it in Javascript like so:

```
var fu1 = document.getElementById('<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>');
```

Don't forget the `runat="server"` on the control.

Comment: you don't use <%# with variables or control ids. it is for databound stuff only.